# Full Height Scrolling with CSS 3

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am trying to layout a web page. My web page will have a search box in the upper left corner. Below the search box are my navigation items. The main content will go in the right area. I am using Zurb Foundation 5 in an effort to create this. Currently, my HTML looks like the following:

```
<div class="full-width full-height" style='width: 100%; max-width: 100%; height:100%;'>
    <div class="large-3 columns" style="overflow-y:scroll; background-color:cornsilk;">
        <div class="row collapse">
            <div class="small-12 columns">
                <input id='search' type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 columns">
                <!-- My vertical list of navigation items will go here in a <ul> -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="large-9 columns">
        <!-- The main content will go here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I need the left portion to have a background color of 'cornsilk'. It should always take up the full height of the screen. This works. If there are more navigation items than space available, a scroll bar needs to be used only for the navigation items. In other words, I need the search box to always be visible. At this time, this is not working. The scroll bar I've created extends below the visible page area. I also have the following related CSS

```
*{ padding:0; margin:0}
html, body { height:100% }
```

How do I

a) Get the scroll bar to work within the bounds of the navigation area?

b) ensure that it is right aligned flush against the border of the navigation area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your looking for is `overflow: auto`

this should be placed on the navigation container .. you could add a `.navigation` class on that container

```
<div class="large-3 columns" style="overflow-y:scroll; background-color:cornsilk;">
    <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <input id='search' type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row NAVIGATION"> <!-- Add class to target nav -->
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <!-- My vertical list of navigation items will go here in a <ul> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then the CSS would be:

```
.navigation {
  overflow: auto;
  height: whatever you want it to be;
}
```

**EDIT:**

basesd on your Fiddle . i made the navigation with oveflow auto http://jsfiddle.net/yxMn3/1/

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. I removed the overflow-y:scroll on the root div thinking that was causing a conflict. That did not help though.

Comment: can u make a fiddle pls ? i can fix that

Comment: Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yxMn3/. Oddly, it doesn't render horizontally though. I'm not experienced with JSFiddle. Maybe foundation isn't being loaded properly?